# Add colors on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am doing a project which contains mapview. I need to change the look of MapView by adding different color on mapview. i already know that we can add route, circle etc on mapview.I am attaching an image below. If anybody knows then please give me a hint that how this is possible. Help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.[image]

Comment: Look for " how to add overlay image to mapview in iOS or xcode " it may need some work but that's the way to go about it.

Comment: The [HazardMap sample app from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049) may provide some hints.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina thanks for giving me the most appropriate sample.Thanks man